# CSS create responsive circle with text inside and image on top of circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a quite difficult html design I want to implement. However, I have absolutely no clue how I can create a circle with text inside AND have a little image on top of the circle.

All this has to be responsive which makes it even more difficult.
This is how I can create a circle. But this one is not responsive..

The rounded image should lay on top of the circle ring in the upper right corner and the text should be centered. Vertically as well as horizontally!

```css
#circle-text {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#circle-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle-text">
<img id="circle-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `::before` to create a polygon form for your text. And also add `position: relative;` to `circle-text` so your image position will be relative te `circle-text`

```css
  #circle-text {
                position: relative;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                border-color: black;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
            }

            #circle-image {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                right: 0px;
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 100px;
            }

            #circle-text::before {
                content: "";
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
                shape-outside: polygon(
                    0 0,
                    98% 0,
                    50% 6%,
                    23.4% 17.3%,
                    6% 32.6%,
                    0 50%,
                    6% 65.6%,
                    23.4% 82.7%,
                    50% 94%,
                    98% 100%,
                    0 100%
                );
                shape-margin: 7%;
            }

            #circle-text span::before {
                content: "";
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                float: right;
                shape-outside: polygon(
                    2% 0%,
                    100% 0%,
                    100% 100%,
                    2% 100%,
                    50% 94%,
                    76.6% 82.7%,
                    94% 65.6%,
                    100% 50%,
                    94% 32.6%,
                    76.6% 17.3%,
                    50% 6%
                );
                shape-margin: 7%;
            }
```

```html
 <div id="circle-text">
            <img id="circle-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats create! But isn't that still not responsive? Because you use fixed sizes?

Comment: Do you need the #circle-text not to have a fixed size?

Comment: Yes, the `#circle-text` just should take the sizes of width and height of the parent element!

Comment: Is the parent fixed size?

Comment: The parent element is not fixed as well because its a responsive website